# MySQL causing fatal error after executing query with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating a method that will execute a query with one or more parameters.

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQueryWithParameters<T>(string Query, string ConnectionString, string[] ParametersArray, string[] ValuesArray)
{
    using (MySqlConnection Connection= new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Connection))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ParametersArray.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParametersArray[i], ValuesArray[i]);
            }

            Connection.Open();
            return Connection.Query<T>(Query);
        }
    }
}
```

`Tempsave` table structure:

```
+------------------------------+
|Id|Localization|Items|Quantity|
+------------------------------+
```

How it works:

When called, the method will receive 4 parameters:

1. A `query` (example: `SELECT * FROM TempSave WHERE Localization  = @Localization`)
2. A connection string (example: `server=localhost; database=wintestbeta;user=root; password=;`)
3. A string array that contains one or more parameters (they look like this: `@Parameter1`)
4. A string array that contains one ore more values

Then it will create a new variable of type `MySqlConnection` called `Connection` with one parameter, the `ConnectionString`.

After that it will create another variable type `MySqlCommand` called `cmd` with two parameters, one is the query and the other is the connection.

Then it will enter a for loop with the size of the `ParametersArray` length, inside the for loop it will add a new parameter to `cmd` with two parameters, the `ParameterArray` with index equal to `i`, and a `ValueArray` with index also equal to `i`.

Then it will open a connection and execute the query, what it receives from the query it will return.

Code used to debug:

```
IEnumerable<TempSave> _CheckTemp;

string Check_TempSave = "SELECT * FROM tempsave WHERE Localization=@Localization";

string[] Parameters = new string[] { "@Localization" };
string[] Values = new string[] { _Save.Localization };

_CheckTemp = SQL.ExecuteQueryWithParameters<TempSave>(Check_TempSave, SQL.ConnectionString, Parameters, Values);
```

**Problem:**

When executing the code when it reaches

```
return Connection.Query<T>(Query);
```

and causes the following error:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

When debugging I checked and both parameters and values only have one value that is:

```
@Localization
Counter,1
```

Comment: can you post your table structure for `TempSave`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i found was instead of using AddWithValue using a for loop and replacing every @Parameter with the value letting the method look like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQueryWithParameters<T>(string Query, string ConnectionString, string[] ParametersArray, string[] ValuesArray)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection Connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
                for (int i = 0; i < ParametersArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Replace all @Parameters
                    Query = Query.Replace(ParametersArray[i], ValuesArray[i]);
                }
                Connection.Open();
                return Connection.Query<T>(Query);
        }
    }
```

Maybe this isn't the best method but no one was answering my question and this was the only solution i come with.